# CBPeripheral name is sometimes null

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-bluetooth

I'm working on developing an app to communicate with a Bluetooth LE peripheral.  The peripheral I am testing with at the moment is one of [these](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2540dk-mini).  The interesting thing is, sometimes when I discover it I get its proper name, "SimpleBLEPeripheral", sometimes I just get `(null)`.  There doesn't seem to be any command I can send to the CBPeripheral to force a read update on the name, so how can I ensure that I actually get the advertised name of the peripheral?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you get the name from the advertisingData NSDictionary it will always be the name that is in the advertising packet sent by the peripheral.

However, if you read the name property of a CBPeripheral object, that name may vary. We try to provide the best name know to us at the time. If we have not yet connected to the peripheral, we will provided the name from the advertising packet. If a connection to the peripheral has been made in the past, we will have read the GAP name. We consider the GAP name to be a 'better' name than what is in the advertising packet (due to the size constraints of the advertising packet).

Comment: That seems to be working, I just don't know where the value `kCBAdvDataLocalName` is defined so that I can include it.  When I print out the advertisement data, that is the key that goes with the name, but I don't know how to retrieve it without that constant value

Comment: I was able to locate the key for the name in the core bluetooth framework reference.  It is a const named `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey`.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I have found that works around this problem is to start scanning and stop scanning, and eventually all the devices I expect to find in the physical space show up with non-nil names and non-nil UUIDs.

Comment: I could not get this working.  After I stop and re-start scan, or even stop and re-start advertising, I still get GATT name ('iPad' because my device is ipad).  Only once do I see peripheral.name = advertised name.  But listen to THIS mystery:  if peripheral ad data name key has 28 character name, central ad data is empty, because that's too long (with UUID), BUT central's periphal.name ONE TIME shows the 28 character name.  This has potential because I could pack 28 bytes of data into peripheral's ad data to save time and battery instead of extra read exchange to get data.  How can I do this?