# peripheral.name always returns null in CoreBluetooth Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I have been trying to get the name of the nearby peripheral devices. It is detecting the peripheral by showing its identifier, RSSI but not displaying the name. I have turned on bluetooth in iPhone 5s, Android mobile, Mac OS. I'm confused which one it is detecting.

I checked if the name is displayed in LightBlue App. It shows only "Unnamed". Pls help.

Comment: This is what I get it in console:          

**<CBPeripheral: 0x17655b40, identifier = 373101DE-66D2-F4D6-F335-9E720AE6F58B, name = (null), state = disconnected>
<CBPeripheral: 0x1768a690, identifier = A9B89C62-2071-2A44-9F2B-3267BDA7E83C, name = (null), state = disconnected>**

Comment: What's your scanning options? Did you wait until it reappears again? Because adv data is limited, it may be updated by chunk.

Comment: I'm using the following line to scan for peripherals. **self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)**  It scans other device I believe because UUID differs. In that too, the device name is null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265028/cbperipheral-name-is-sometimes-null Check if name is null, then "forget it". And wait until it reappears.

Comment: I tried this. But whenever I re-scan, it simply throws null in the name.

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899838/not-able-to-scan-through-cbcentral-manager-with-service-id-for-ibecon-signal/41955750#41955750

Comment: This line itself let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary).objectForKey(CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as? NSString gives only null value. But identifier is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

first, I scan with some options.

```
manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil,
                                   options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:true, CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnConnectionKey: false, CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey: false, CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnNotificationKey: false])
```

pay attention to **CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey** scan option, read about it. It is not necessary to make it true. Just in my case.

Then I am checking in

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)
```

If the name is exist in **AdvertisementData** or on instance of **CBPeripheral**

If name not exposed – so, possible to make a connection attempt

```
central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
```

and then to listen to method of **CBPeripheral delegate**

```
func peripheralDidUpdateName(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral)
```

Where you actually can get updated name

And them I am immediately disconnecting

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        central.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
    }
```

Under the hood it happens because peripheral can broadcast their data splitted to few parts and often the name is not the first-comer.

Comment: CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:true this saved my life. Thank you!